# Does it make sense, literarily, to speak of a "smiling sun"?

Tags: word-choice

I am writing a short story in which I have hitherto exploited several literary techniques to portray a bright and beautiful sun in the paleness of a blue sky. To retract from employing the same techniques exhaustively, I have tried to describe the sun as a "smiling" one in the endeavour to portray its beauty and brightness and the general positive atmosphere of the setting. I was wondering if such a description makes sense.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a writing advice request.

Comment: The poster was asking if this *usage* makes sense... Seems on-topic to me.

Comment: @MετάEd Not really, I merely asked whether it makes sense to speak of a "smiling sun", not whether I should consult other techniques or alter anything. In other words, I did not request for any recommendations whatsoever, however, I do concede in requesting for an objective (in regards to my word-choice) "Yes" or "No" answer which cannot be classified as an "advice request".

Comment: "Smiling" with reference to the sun is a metaphor, yes. Whether it makes sense or not depends on the particular application and the rest of the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sounds fine.

This metaphor has certainly been used before. [This](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22smiling%20sun%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1979,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl) site can show you where the phrase "smiling sun" occurs in some books.

Comment: Thanks, I tried "googling" the word but I could not find any references from any books whatsoever, I think it's because I didn't click on the book section.